# Android rounded corner around full List view with different color rows example

Tags: android, listview, colors, row, rounded-corners

Hi I am trying to implement entire list view in a rounded corner with different list view row colors.

I am able to implement rounded corner to the entire list view. But the rows with different colors was not able to fit in the rounded corner list view specially at the top and bottom of the list view because this has the rounded corner.

Please help regarding this issue

Comment: Share your code here for getting more idea on what you doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `ListView` inside of `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_Bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_item_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:scrollingCache="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_item_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#04A3C3" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
</shape>
```

Change margin, padding and color as per your requirements

If after this code, your problem not solve then send your UI code.